# Rename or give alias to Python Spark dataframe column names

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I am using PySpark 2.4.3 and I have a dataframe that I wish to write to Parquet, but the column names have spaces, such as `Hour of day`.

```
df = spark.read.csv("file.csv", header=True)
df.write.parquet('input-parquet/')
```

I am getting this error currently:

```
An error occurred while calling o425.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Attribute name "Hour of day" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.;
```

How can I either rename the columns or give them aliases to be able to write to Parquet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename the column with the `withColumnRenamed(existing, new)` method, and then write to parquet. It would be something like this:

```
df.withColumnRenamed('Hour of day', 'Hour')
```

Comment: This did it, so simple! Thank you