# Using alias to rename pyspark columns

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm trying to import a parquet file in Databricks (pyspark) and keep getting the error

```
df = spark.read.parquet(inputFilePath)

AnalysisException:  Column name "('my data (beta)', "Meas'd Qty")" contains invalid character(s). Please use alias to rename it.
```

I tried the suggestions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57123300/rename-or-give-alias-to-python-spark-dataframe-column-names), using `.withColumnRenamed` like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38191157/spark-dataframe-validating-column-names-for-parquet-writes), and also using `alias` like

```
(spark.read.parquet(inputFilePath)).select(col("('my data (beta)', "Meas'd Qty")").alias("col")).show()
```

but always get the same error. How do I go through each column to replace any invalid characters with underscore `_` or even just delete all invalid characters?

Comment: You can refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38191157/spark-dataframe-validating-column-names-for-parquet-writes OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45804534/pyspark-org-apache-spark-sql-analysisexception-attribute-name-contains-inv

Comment: thanks, I tried both but get the same error - the error occurs at the line `spark.read.parquet(inputFilePath)` and nothing I do seems to give me a different result

Comment: you can try , df = df.withColumnRenamed("Foo Bar", "foobar") . remove the additional space in column

Comment: like I said, I get the same error when doing that

Comment: can you provide the sample inputfile to get more clarity on the column names?

Answer (score 0):

How is the old file generated? The file was saved with column names that are not allowed by the spark.

Better to fix this issue at the source when this file is generated.

Few approaches you can try in spark to resolve are

1. In the select statement put column name in `` like

```py
(spark.read.parquet(inputFilePath)).select(col(`('my data (beta)', "Meas'd Qty")`).alias("col")).show()
```

2. Try to rename using `toDF`. You need to pass all the column names in the output df.

```
(spark.read.parquet(inputFilePath)).toDF(["col_a", "col_b", ...]).show()
```

3. Try reading the file using pyarrow and refactor the columns and save the result. After that read using pysaprk and continue with your tasks.

Comment: the original files are from a database and I don't control the formatting ...  1. i get invalid syntax error for the ``  and 2. invalid syntax error when I put the column name in `""`

Comment: Exactly what are the column names in the source ?

Comment: it's actually a multi index - when I import the parquet file outside databricks, I can see the column names: `MultiIndex([('my data (alpha)', 'Meas'd Qty'), ('my data (alpha)', 'Sch Qty'), ('my data (beta)', 'Meas'd Qty'), ...`

Comment: Approach #3, 

Try reading the file using pyarrow and refactor the columns and save the result. After that read using pyspark and continue with your tasks.

Comment: thanks, I'll try that. It's disappointing though that databricks can't parse multi index parquet files